# Android - How to add google maps inside AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-appbarlayout

I'm stuck on a problem, was wondering ya'll could help me out!
I've been trying to achieve this layout over here:

[image]

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/mapView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/viewpager_id"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat="7.0725543"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng="125.6135548"
            mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="12"
            mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl="mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v10" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tablayoutid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="213dp"
            android:background="@color/tabBackground"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tabTextColor"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tabTextColor" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView" />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:padding="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/mapView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/matina_dropdown"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:dropDownWidth="200dp"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                mapbox:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                mapbox:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener, OnMapReadyCallback{

private MapboxMap mapboxMap;
private MapView mapView;
private TabLayout tablayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tablayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayoutid);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager_id);

    //Creates the fragment (tab)
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentFlood(),"Flood");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentWeather(), "Explore");
    adapter.AddFragment(new FragmentAnalytics(),"Analytics");


    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
}
```

The application keeps crashing and the tablayout is not showing, neither its contents.

What I've done so far was initialize MapBox in the layout. Most Android tabs tutorial manipulate the entire page but I wanted the tab to affect only the contents below it, but not the map. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: `MapFragment` is dependent, meaning you can always put them on any parent layout. Can you provide the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Do you want to scroll the map box like the toolbar in CollapsingToolbarLayout?

Comment: @BashorunOlajide edited the question details!

Comment: @Nainal Nope, I couldn't make the TabLayout to show under the Map. I primarily thought I was doing it wrong. Edited the question.

Comment: @CodeCodeCode Post your logcat error.